# PHP - Infinite while loop from class

Tags: php, function, loops, class

I'm trying to create a while loop from the returned execution of a PDO statement in a class call Posts, but it's creating an infinite while loop even though **the number of rows returns correct**. This seems simple...Am I writing this wrong?

```
public function getRecent()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY createdate DESC LIMIT 5";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;

}

$post = NEW Posts($db);

echo $post->getRecent()->rowCount(); //5 results(correct)

while ($row = $post->getRecent()->fetch())
{
    //Creates infinite loop
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that every time you call `$post->getRecent()` it executes your query again and so `$post->getRecent()->fetch()` then returns the first row of the result set over and over again. Just make one call to `$post->getRecent()` and use that value in place of the other calls:

```
$post = NEW Posts($db);
$result = $post->getRecent();
echo $result->rowCount();
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    // process rows
}
```

Comment: @prosportal we've all been there. Sometimes you just need that second pair of eyes to look at the code.